is there a difference between calorie deficit induced by less caloric intake and more caloric output for muscle preservation?
for example, going on 300 calorie deficit by just eating less fat, or partially eating less and adding moderate cardio or fully by cardio. what would be the impact for muscle perservation and muscle building during this phase?

Assuming you're ingesting an adequate amount of protein, a high energy flux diet (high energy expenditure combined with adequate caloric intake) helps preserve lean mass by stimulating muscle protein synthesis.
Regular resistance training, maintains muscle tissue by counteracting muscle breakdown often triggered by caloric deficits in low-calorie diets. Additionally, the enhanced metabolic rate from high energy turnover prevents the body's shift into a conservation mode, where lean mass is metabolized for energy. This mechanism promotes fat loss while sparing muscle, ensuring better body composition and long-term metabolic health.
The main problem with low calorie diets is that they often result in significant reductions in energy expenditure. This happens through metabolic adaptation, where the body lowers its basal metabolic rate to conserve energy, making weight loss harder and increasing the likelihood of weight regain. Additionally, without adequate protein intake or resistance training, the body may break down muscle tissue for energy, leading to muscle loss. This further slows metabolism, as lean muscle is metabolically active and critical for maintaining a higher caloric burn at rest.
So to counter David's excellent answer:

you do add more exercise while not reducing your calories (maybe it's not more cardio, maybe you're just able to lift heavier or add more reps)
you will spend more energy since you're moving more
because you ingest an adequate amount of calories, you can recover faster (so you might not be more tired during the day, your metabolism is not slowing down)
you're not eating less, so you won't feel so hungry


The only thing likely to preserve muscle is engaging in resistance training.
As for the difference between eating 300 kcal less food per day, and doing 300 kcal more cardio, you're less likely to actually achieve your target caloric deficit by increase cardio, compared to reducing food intake.
The reasons for this are:

Machines and devices that measure caloric expenditure during exercise are notorious for overestimating calories burned.
You cannot just add calories burned during exercise to your normal daily caloric expenditure, because by doing so you're ignoring the calories that you would have burned during that same time period even if you weren't exercising. E.g. If you exercise for 1 hour and burn 300 kcal in that time, but your baseline metabolic rate at rest is 100 kcal/hour anyway, then you didn't add 300 kcal to your daily expenditure, you only added 200 kcal, since you replaced a 100 kcal activity with a 300 kcal activity.
Adding up calories from exercise fails to take into account energy compensation. So you burned 300 kcal during exercise in the morning. What if you're now more tired during the day, and as a result, move less, and burn 150 kcal less during the afternoon? Now you only added 150 kcal to your daily expenditure.


Assuming adequate protein, of course.
